# IN meteor how to upload album with text

Tags: image, meteor, file-upload, upload

Anyone know package?

I want to upload album with text on every image.

Basically I want to upload multiple image and every image must contain textbox for text. in meteor.

I want to store images' name in array for every user.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, you should try CFS: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Comment: The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.
CollectionFS is giving error. and CollectionFS insert every time new row for every image

Comment: Enable debug mode: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Getting-Started

You should check if file already exists before you save it - AFAIK you can use beforeWrite.

Comment: GET FILERECORD: cewsBSjcpKgCx5cns
VM440 cfs_upload-http.js?hash=de2b2d8…:371 PUT to URL /cfs/files/yourFileCollection/cewsBSjcpKgCx5cns Objectfilename: "7.jpg"token: "eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiJMZzJyUy13SVptb19hYi1xRHl1R3lJMVl1OU1HM1h4cXdnLWYxckhmQ1gtIn0="__proto__: Object
VM440 cfs_upload-http.js?hash=de2b2d8…:140 The provided value 'undefined' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.
httpCall @ VM440 cfs_upload-http.js?hash=de2b2d8…:140
gotBinaryCallback @ VM440 cfs_upload-http.js?hash=de2b2d8…:373
reader.onload @ cfs_data-man.js?hash=7f26bfa…:336